# Use svg element as bingmap pushpin icon

Tags: bing-maps

Is there a way to use an svg element as an icon for the Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin?

I created an svg

element like this:

```
var fillcolor = "#ff0222";
var svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg1.setAttribute("height",50);
svg1.setAttribute("width",50);

var circles = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circles.setAttribute("cx",25);
circles.setAttribute("cy",25);
circles.setAttribute("r",25);
circles.setAttribute("fill",fillcolor);
svg1.appendChild(circles);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin it is possible to set the options (PushpinOptions) where you can specify the htmlContent property to the value of your choice.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427629.aspx

And the iSDK sample: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#Pushpins15

The code should be inspired by something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Add pushpin with options</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;

      function getMap()
      {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'});
      }

      function addCustomPushpin()
      {
        var pushpinOptions = {width: null, height: null, htmlContent: "<div style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;border:solid 2px;background-color:LightBlue;width:100px;'>Custom Pushpin</div>"}; 
        var pushpin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), pushpinOptions);
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="getMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
      <div>
         <input type="button" value="AddCustomPushpin" onclick="addCustomPushpin();" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where am placing svg object ?/